# Parallelize simple for loop using Pytorch on single GPU

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have a for-loop which operates on independent columns of a large matrix. I have parallelized the for-loop on CPU using the prange function in Numba. Now I want to perform this operation using PyTorch tensors on a GPU. I'm a PyTorch novice and don't know how to do it.

Any help will be really appreciated.

My Python code is as follows:

```
def select_next(X, gains, current_values, mask):
    for idx in prange(X.shape[0]):
        if mask[idx] == 1:
            continue

        a = numpy.maximum(X[idx], current_values)
        gains[idx] = (a - current_values).sum()
    return numpy.argmax(gains)
```

My PyTorch code is as follows:

```
def select_next(X, gains, current_values, mask):
    for idx in range(X.shape[0]):
        if mask[idx].item() == 1:
            continue

        a = torch.max(X[idx], current_values)
        gains[idx] = torch.sum(torch.sub(a, current_values))
    return torch.argmax(gains)
```

How can I parallelize the for loops?

Comment: Convert all the inputs onto GPU using `variable_name = variable_name.cuda()` and find equivalent PyTorch functions of the NumPy functions you are using from PyTorch documentation and replace them.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have replaced all the variables with their corresponding PyTorch analogues, but I can't seem to figure out how I can parallelize the for loop itself. Numba does not parallelize the for loop with torch tensors as input, so wanted to know if there's an alternative to it in PyTorch.

Answer (score 0):

APPy (https://github.com/habanero-lab/APPy) could be a good fit for your case, if you need to parallelize a simple for loop on the GPU. It supports torch gpu and cupy tensors as inputs. The APPy parallelized version of `select_next` based on your pytorch code looks like this:

```py
@appy.jit
def select_next_appy(X, gains, current_values, mask, N):
    #pragma parallel for
    for idx in range(X.shape[0]):
        if mask[idx] != 1:            
            a = torch.maximum(X[idx, :N], current_values[:N])            
            gains[idx] = torch.sum(a - current_values[:N])
    return torch.argmax(gains)
```

Basically by adding some annotations to the code, you can get the loop parallelized.

I have also benchmarked and compared the performance of the APPy implementation above and a pytorch version (similar to your code) using
a 1000x1000 sized matrix "X". The APPy parallelized version takes about 0.18ms while the torch version takes about 89ms. Here's the complete test code:

```py
def select_next_torch(X, gains, current_values, mask, N):
    for idx in range(X.shape[0]):
        if mask[idx] != 1:
            a = torch.maximum(X[idx, :N], current_values)
            gains[idx] = torch.sum(a - current_values)
    return torch.argmax(gains)


@appy.jit
def select_next_appy(X, gains, current_values, mask, N):
    #pragma parallel for
    for idx in range(X.shape[0]):
        if mask[idx] != 1:            
            a = torch.maximum(X[idx, :N], current_values[:N])            
            gains[idx] = torch.sum(a - current_values[:N])
    return torch.argmax(gains)


torch.set_default_device('cuda')

M, N = 1000, 1000
X = torch.randn(M, N)
gains = torch.randn(M)
mask = torch.randn(M) > 1
current_values = torch.randn(N)

result = select_next_torch(X, gains, current_values, mask, N)
result1 = select_next_appy(X, gains, current_values, mask, N)
assert(result == result1)
for f in [select_next_torch, select_next_appy]:
    ms = appy.utils.bench(lambda: f(X, gains, current_values, mask, N))
    print(f"{f.__name__}: {ms:.4f} ms")
```

Comment: In my tests, the original PyTorch code is faster on CPU vs GPU for the the test input you share. (I think the problem is too small to get the benefit of the GPU.) But I also get a speed-up by simply vectorizing the function (this is actually improved by using the GPU since it's more intensive).